# empty URL is not returning as I set from app-routing.module

Tags: angular8, angular-router

When I hit `http://localhost:4200/` then I expected `http://localhost:4200/dashboard` to be loaded and the code below is the `app-routing.module.ts`. 
As I put the line of `{path: '', redirectTo: 'dashboard', pathMatch: 'full'},`, i think it must direct to the dashboard but it's not working as intended.

```
const routes: Routes = [
{ path: 'auth', loadChildren: () => import('app/views/pages/auth/auth.module').then(m => m.AuthModule)},

{
    path: '',
    component: BaseComponent,
    canActivate: [AuthGuard],
    children: [
        {
            path: 'dashboard',
            loadChildren: () => import('app/views/pages/dashboard/dashboard.module').then(m => m.DashboardModule)
        },

        {
            path:'create-job',
            loadChildren:()=>import('app/views/pages/create-job/create-job.module').then(m=>m.CreateJobModule)
        },
        {
            path: 'mail',
            loadChildren: () => import('app/views/pages/apps/mail/mail.module').then(m => m.MailModule)
        },
        {
            path: 'ecommerce',
            loadChildren: () => import('app/views/pages/apps/e-commerce/e-commerce.module').then(m => m.ECommerceModule),
        },
        {
            path: 'ngbootstrap',
            loadChildren: () => import('app/views/pages/ngbootstrap/ngbootstrap.module').then(m => m.NgbootstrapModule)
        },
        { 
            path: 'material',
            loadChildren: () => import('app/views/pages/material/material.module').then(m => m.MaterialModule)
        },
        {
            path: 'user-management',
            loadChildren: () => import('app/views/pages/user-management/user-management.module').then(m => m.UserManagementModule)
        },
        {
            path: 'wizard',
            loadChildren: () => import('app/views/pages/wizard/wizard.module').then(m => m.WizardModule)
        },
        {
            path: 'builder',
            loadChildren: () => import('app/views/theme/content/builder/builder.module').then(m => m.BuilderModule)
        },
        {
            path: 'error/403',
            component: ErrorPageComponent,
            data: {
                type: 'error-v6',
                code: 403,
                title: '403... Access forbidden',
                desc: 'Looks like you don\'t have permission to access for requested page.<br> Please, contact administrator'
            }
        },
        {path: 'error/:type', component: ErrorPageComponent},
        {path: '', redirectTo: 'dashboard', pathMatch: 'full'}, 
        {path: '**', redirectTo: 'dashboard', pathMatch: 'full'}
    ]
},

{path: '**', redirectTo: 'error/403', pathMatch: 'full'},
];
```

Comment: if you could post the `dashboard-routing.module.ts` ?

Comment: @HarikrishnanS I don't have dashboard module but i have just module having that path
  RouterModule.forChild([
   {
    path: "",
    component: DashboardComponent,
   },
  ]),